# How to copy the folder from one directory to another in perl?

Tags: perl

I want to copy the folder from one directory to another.

For Example
I have folder in D drive like Sample it that itself contain many folder.I want to copy this sample folder with its sub folders to some other drive.Here i have done something but it copies only the files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy,

my $source_dir = "aa";
my $target_dir = "bb";

opendir(my $DIR, $source_dir) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!";  
my @files = readdir($DIR);

foreach my $t (@files)
{
   if(-f "$source_dir/$t" ) {
      #Check with -f only for files (no directories)
      copy "$source_dir/$t", "$target_dir/$t";
   }
}

closedir($DIR);
```

Please help with this...

Thanks in advance

Comment: [use File::Copy::Recursive;](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/File-Copy-Recursive-0.38/Recursive.pm)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use either the [`File::Copy::Recursive`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Copy::Recursive) module, which has a number of related functions from which you probably want `dircopy`; or the [`File::Mirror`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Mirror) module, which has a `mirror` function that does the same as `dircopy`, plus a `recursive` function that allows you to provide a block of code to control exactly how the nodes will be copied.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw(dircopy);
dircopy($source_dir,$target_dir) or die("$!\n");
```